# Unable to connect to RDS MySQL database from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have created a RDS MYSQL database and have set public access , modified VPC security groups [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LcUL.png)

but I am still not able to connect to the MYSql. Telnet also fails Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed

Connection from mysql workbench gives the following error `Can't connect to MySQL server at .... (10061)`

I've checked various posts in stack exchange on this error . But still unable to figure out what is missing.

Kindly let me know what is missing.

Comment: I am not sure. But it is highly doubtful that RDS will allow connections through TCP. Normally RDS on AWS will run on Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) connections with DB instances running the MySQL database engine only. So, your inbound security changes in opening a port shall not help

Comment: @RTM I am having the same problem right now. Can you describe how were you trying to connect?

Answer (score 2):

Some things to check:

- The RDS instance should be configured as **publicly accessible**
- The RDS instance should be launched in a **public subnet**
- The Security Group should permit **Inbound** access for your IP address for port 3306
- Your network must not be blocking the connection (try from another network, such as work/home or tethered via your phone)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response! I am able to successfully connect from my home network with the same settings. So what do I need to change in my work network to be able to connect?

Comment: If the Security Group has the IP address for your home, then you'll need to change it to the IP address from which your work traffic appears to come. You can ask Google for "my ip". If the Security Group is permitting inbound access from `0.0.0.0/0`, then this allows access from _anywhere_ on the Internet, so the problem lies in the configuration of your corporate network. You will need to talk with your network administrators to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks John! I am talking to my network team on this , to check if any port is blocked etc . Is there any means for me to check from my machine if a port is blocked. If I need to check which ports should I check? I am using a windows 10 machine.

Comment: If you can't reach something, then it is blocked somewhere between your computer and the destination. That's about all you can see.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and added a custom inbound rule in my security group with the port number from my database and the source set to my IP. this fixed it for me and telnet started working.